# xhtml2pdf: background-color does not fill frame

Tags: python, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I have a GAE python server whom I send data from a form, and according to this data the server creates a pdf-compatible html string, converts it to pdf using pisa/xhtml2pdf and sends the pdf file to the user.
The output is a graph made using divs/frames, the position/size is automatically calculated, and the frames have a certain background colour, depending on some data. However, the background color is only rendered behind text, not in the full frame.
Is there a fix for that? I know reportlab's canvas can fill color, so can i manipulate the pisa files to do that for me? Or is there some other, more dirty trick like using coloured background images or something?